# How to make my class function like a ListItem when binding my repeater?

Tags: c#, list, class, repeater, listitem

I need to populate a set of repeater drop down list items from a custom class but cannot seem to figure it out. It works perfectly when I use just a standard `ListItem` collection, but for some reason my custom class only returns a bunch of empty drop down lists. I'm new to repeaters and am trying to understand them the best I can, but this one kind of has me beat. Code is shown below. I have a base class that contains a child class, the child class is used to populate the drop down lists. When `ListItemOptions` is set to just a `List<ListItem>', the actual type of`ListItem', it works perfect. Why doesn't my repeater like my class?

```
// My base class. FYI: there are about 20 other properties in this class. I'm not just aimlessly jumping to a child class for fun!
public class ConfiguratorOption
{
    private List<ListItemOptions> _listItemOptions = new List<ListItemOptions>();

    public ConfiguratorOption() { }

    public List<ListItemOptions> ListItemOptions { get { return _listItemOptions; } set { _listItemOptions = value; } }
    public void AddListItemOption(string nodeId, string value, string displayName)
    {
        ListItemOptions lioNew = new ListItemOptions();
        NodeID = nodeId;
        Value = value;
        DisplayName = displayName;
        ListItemOptions.Add(lioNew);
    }
}

// The child class. 
public class ListItemOptions : IEnumerable
{
    private string _nodeID = string.Empty;
    private string _displayName = string.Empty;
    private string _value = string.Empty;

    public ListItemOptions() { }

    public string NodeID { get { return _nodeID; } set { _nodeID = value; } }
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    public string DisplayName { get { return _displayName; } set { _displayName = value; } }
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (IEnumerator)this;
    }
}

// The infamous repeater...
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptConfigurationOptions">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="ConfigurationBlock">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddnOption" runat="server" CssClass="DropDownStandard" style="width: 500px;" DataTextField="DisplayName"  DataValueField="Value" AutoPostBack="true" 
            DataSource='<%# Eval("ListItemOptions") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddnOption_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

// And the repeater code..
private void BindRepeater<T>(Repeater rpt, List<T> cOp)
{
    rpt.Controls.Clear();
    rpt.DataSource = cOp;
    rpt.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Eval` this way.  `Eval` will essentially evaluate the property and return a string.  In your case that could render out looking like:

```
<asp:dropdown DataSource='List<ListItemOptions>'/>
```

Don't set the datasource via `Eval`.  Handle the repeater's `ItemDataBound` event and set the DropDownList's datasource manually to the actual property.